# Why I'm redirected to some questions while using just numbers?

Tags: support, search

When I am in a question like
[MySQL Error 2049: Authentication protocol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815242/mysql-error-2049-authentication-protocol-error) (or any other post in the main site, or in any of the review sites `https://stackoverflow.com/review/...`)
and I search in the upper searchbox the number 2048 I go directly to a question [Monitor a specific RSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048/monitor-a-specific-rss).
Which has the url with `.../questions/2048/...`

As noted in comments and the answer there are other numbers like the `4563341` which also redirect to a question, while others like 456334 or 2047 don't. **If it is a feature of the elasticsearch how is this performed? When does it search the question number `n` and when does it search for post containing the number `n`?**

I use Chromium Version 47.0.2526.73 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit), I don't know if it is just my browser or anything related to my configuration, but I bet it is not just for me.
I tested with Mozilla Firefox 43.0 for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0 and I observed the same problem.
Sorry I don't have any screenshot

Comment: I think that if there's no results returned for a solely numeric search your search terms get's replaced with the question with that ID. For instance, searching for `456334` on SO returns one question but searching for `4563341` sends you straight to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563341/javascript-compare-graphically-two-json-xml-objects. If it's not been specifically redirected I suspect this'll be a "feature" of elasticsearch...

Comment: Whoever thought that was a good idea, ...

Comment: Oh, yes I forgot to mention I tried other numbers, but none of them redirected me to a question. Then if this due to a featurewhen does it search the question number n and when does it search for post containing the number n?

Comment: You are on Meta and it doesn't happen here - for anyone else who just tried it and got quite confused as to why they weren't taken to the given questions.

Comment: _"You are on Meta and it doesn't happen here"_ I actually just tried it with this question's number and it worked for me here on meta. @RyanfaeScotland Are you sure you picked a question's id number?

Comment: @Kendra you appear to be right, I guess there just isn't a question 2048, 456334 or 2047 on Meta (Please forgive me, I didn't check all the positive integer numbers)

Answer (score 26):

Since the other answer concentrate on the "why" here's what to do about it: if you notice that searching for `2048` takes you directly to a question just search for `"2048"` which will search for all posts containing `2048`.

Answer (score 23):

[It's a feature:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43931/213575)

> Already exists. Searching for a specific question ID will take you to that question.
>
> Proof? Try searching for "43410" right now.
>
> **This does not work for answers, however.**

For example, if you search for this answer post id https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=313917 it will search the number, unlike if you use https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=313916 which is this question id it will redirect you to this question. If an id has not been used, then the search will proceed as usual.

Comment: Note that `2047` doesn't because [it's really an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535/reducing-duplicate-error-handling-code-in-c/2047#2047), and the same applies [for `456334`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456296/dealing-with-multiple-standards-in-single-class-library/456334#456334). You might also run into deleted questions, which also won't redirect ([try `6976854`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=6976854)).